# Protractor typescript issue while checking value from select menu

Tags: typescript, protractor

[image]I am automating by using protractor typescript I am facing issue while selecting specific value from select menu, please see the screenshot

```
<div class="pq-select-menu">
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-565-0">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Application Administrators(1001)</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable pq-state-hover" id="pq-option-565-1">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Power Users(1002)</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-565-2">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Users(1003)</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-565-3">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">automationGroup(1005)</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-565-4">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">TestGroup2(1024)</span></label>
</div>
```

After clicking on select menu by
`element(by.xpath('.//td[@data-container-for="groups"]//div[@class="pq-select-text"]')).click();` `enter code here`
How I can select and to check if that value is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [xpath axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes). They let you easily find elements relative to one another.

In this case you would identify the `span` tag using the text and find the preceding `input` within the same `label`

```
let inputEle = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[text()="Users(1003)"]/preceding-sibling::input'))

console.log(await inputEle.isSelected()) //should return true or false
```